# Getting 'undefined' as a value in java from Cookie?

Tags: java, gwt, cookies

We are working with java-gwt application. We are using cookies along with all the modules in the application. In some cases i need to get the value from cookie before setting cookie.

```
String demoId = Cookie.get("demoId");
```

In the above code i am getting 'undefined' as demoId. How to handle this in java, because the 'undefined' is specific to javascript.

Comment: java and javascript are not the same

Comment: yes but i am getting 'undefined' in java code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From GWT/Java point of view, JavaScript's `null` and `undefined` are the same: they're Java `null`. Of course they behave differently when running your app (such as when "stringifying" them) but in 99.999% of the cases they just behave the same (note that in JS `(null == undefined) === true`).

So just use an `== null` in Java and it'll work the same whether the value actually is a JS `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Boyer, The 'undefined' is working as null always in firefox only but it is not working in chrome, some times it is working and some times it is not working